# Why doesn't the MCU's pin go high on time?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m3, cortex-m, stm32f10x

I have a [STM32F103](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf) and I downloaded this program to it(a simple blink program):

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f10x.h"

#define SYSCLK_FREQ_72MHz

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

void GPIO_Configuration(void);

void delay(uint32_t a){
    while(a){
        --a;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : main
* Description    : Main Programme
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/


int main(void)
{
    GPIO_Configuration();


    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {
        delay(0x44AA200);
        GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : GPIO_Configuration
* Description    : Configure GPIO Pin
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/
void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB , ENABLE);                        
/**
 *  LED1 -> PB0
 */                  
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}
```

I expected that `delay(0x44AA200);` works for 1s but but when I run it, this delay take 6s!!

**Why?**

Is it related to the 3 stage enhanced pipeline?

this is the RCC configuration and I thing everything is ok:

[image: figure1]

and this is the assembly code:

[image: figure2]

Comment: What caused you to believe the code `while(a){ --a;}` would execute in a single instruction cycle (assuming this STM32F103's clock is set correctly)? It is clear from the assembler listing that it is several instructions. So if we assume it is 6 cycles, the delay of 6s makes sense. It has nothing to do with the pipelining of the processor; it's just how long the machine instructions take. You could correct `delay` by reducing the count by a factor of 6.

Comment: @gbulmer Thanks friend, because I had forgotten it and I'm not familiar with assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your loop 72000000 times.

You seem to think that each loop will take one clock cycle. However, at minimum, even the simplest loop with a counter will take multiple operations: De-increment, compare, conditional jump.

Also, not all assembly operations take just one cycle.

In this case, you have two assembly operations in your loop:

```
0x080000562 SUBS  r0, r0, #1
0x080000564 BNE   0x080000562
```

The `SUBS` flag subtracts, (`SUB` fragment), and sets conditional flags (`S` fragment). 
The BNE does a branch (`B` fragment) if not-equal (`NE` fragment).

The  STM32F103 is a Cortex M3 based processor, which means it uses the `ARMv7-M` architecture. Looking up the [Cortex M3](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337i/CHDDIGAC.html) architecture assembly listing, we see:

```
Operation   Description   Assembler           Cycles  
Subtract    Subtract      SUB Rd, Rn, <op2>   1  
Branch      Conditional   B<cc> <label>       1 or 1 + P
```

So the subtract operation takes 1 cycle, and the branch takes either 1 (if the branch is not taken), or 1 + `P` if it is. `P` in this case is:

> "The number of cycles required for a pipeline refill. This ranges from
>   1 to 3 depending on the alignment and width of the target instruction,
>   and whether the processor manages to speculate the address early"

In total, assuming `P` is 3 in this case, this only results in 5 operations, so I'd assume that either you're seeing a *five* second delay, not six, or it's possible the addition of the `S` fragment to `SUB` causes it to take another clock cycle (but I'm just guessing there).

Comment: +1 for good answer. I had forgotten "De-increment, compare, conditional jump"! unfortunately I'm not familiar with assembly. and about this part"not all assembly operations take just one cycle" are you sure?

Comment: @Roh - About different operations taking different numbers of cycles: Absolutely. The only instruction set I know off the top of my head is the AVR instruction set, but operations can take 1-6+ cycles, depending on what they do.

Comment: Connor, now I think my question was silly although I had forgotten something about assembly. Thanks man for nice answer.

Comment: @Roh - Added assembly dissection.

Comment: I'm sure that there are several reasons that can demonstrate us why it's 6s! crystal and temp and or somethings else that we don't know. Thanks again, your answer is perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

With your CPU running at 72MHz and your delay value 0x44aa200 (72 000 000), you're assuming that the loop in your delay function only takes one CPU clock cycle to execute.

But look at the disassembly - there's far more than just 1 instruction there.

It's been a while since I last used an STM32 so I can't remember exactly how clock frequency translates into instruction execution speed or if there is any pipelining or something similar to consider.

Judging from your observation that your delay appears to take 6 seconds instead of 1, it would seem that each iteration of your delay loop actually takes 6 clock cycles. 
So what you'll need to do is divide your targeted delay value by 6.